# What's a fast way to parse a Wikipedia XML dump for article content and populate a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, wikipedia, text-mining

For some text-mining applications, I need to identify the frequency of every word per article in the English-language Wikipedia and populate a MySQL database with that data. [This official page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aImporting_XML_dumps) suggests using mwdumper or xml2sql on the dump, but they don't directly serve my purpose (unless someone can explain how they can).

Using [WikiExtractor](http://medialab.di.unipi.it/wiki/Wikipedia_Extractor), MySQLdb for Python, and a local MySQL server, on the other hand, allows me to do exactly what I want, but it's slow to the point that it would take a month to parse the entire dump. Profiling the modified WikiExtractor program shows that most of the runtime is spent in its nest regular expression search and my database inserts.

Ideally, I don't want processing the articles to take more than a couple days. How can I do it efficiently?

Comment: `maintenance/importDump.php` was the fastest option for my specific needs. It also works well through GNU Parallel. But unfortunately it's no good if you want to run sensible SQL queries as it will give you MediaWiki SQL...

Answer (score 2):

The Perl package [MediaWiki::DumpFile](http://search.cpan.org/~triddle/MediaWiki-DumpFile-0.2.1/lib/MediaWiki/DumpFile.pm) is good for parsing. To load a dump and read each page you need very few lines of code.

To do a simple word-frequency calculation you can use the [sample code in Perl FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/pod/perlfaq6.pod#How_can_I_print_out_a_word-frequency_or_line-frequency_summary?) or the package [Text::Ngrams](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Ngrams/Ngrams.pm) for something smarter.

Adding the results to a database is up to you, because you are developing the application and you are supposed to know the needs.